# Get list of runtime libraries in Gradle while using 'java-library' and 'api' instead of 'compile'

Tags: java, gradle

I use this code to get the required libraries and copy them during compile:

```
task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}

jar {
    dependsOn copyToLib
    ...
}
```

It's OK when I use the lagecy Gradle model to add dependencies using `compile`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'
    compile 'io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.16.Final'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    ...
}
```

But when I use `api` keyword:

```
dependencies {
    api 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'
    api 'io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.16.Final'
    api 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    ...
}
```

The `configurations.runtime` would be empty. Any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runtime` configuration has also been deprecated, like `compile` configuration ( see documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations )

So you need to change your `from` clause in `copyToLib` task, to pick up a correct configuration :  I think in your case you should use `compileClasspath` (**EDIT** use `runtimeClasspath` instead, see comment below):

```
dependencies {
    api 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'
    api 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    api 'io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.16.Final'
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```

See this configuration dependencies graph that can help you pick up the correct configuration : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph

Comment: Note that this will not include dependencies added to `runtimeOnly` and effectively is about copying the _compile_ classpath. If you want _all runtime_ libraries, you should use `runtimeClasspath`

Comment: @LouisJacomet you are right, thanks. I've updated my answer.